# Distance between a cone and a disjoint hyperplane

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I seek to prove the following, which I guess is true:

> Define $A:=\{x \ge 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and assume that $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is an affine subspace with $A \cap U=\emptyset$. Show that
>
> $$ \delta:=\inf_{\substack{x\ge 0\\x'\in U}}\lVert x-x'\rVert>0.$$

I can easily handle the cases where $\mbox{dim}(U)=0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $U$ is non-empty. $U$ is of the form $u+V$ for some point $u$ and some linear subspace $V.$ Consider the projection map $\phi:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m/V.$ It takes $U$ to a single point which I will denote $[u].$  The distance between $A$ and $U$ is bounded below by (in fact equal to) the distance between $\phi(A)$ and $[u].$ So it remains to show that the distance between $\phi(A)$ and $[u]$ is positive.

Each standard basis vector $e_i$ is taken to a point other than $[u]$ because $e_i\in A$ which is disjoint from $U.$ Since $A$ is a convex cone generated by the rays $e_1,\dots,e_m,$ the set $\phi(A)$ is a convex cone generated by the rays $\phi(e_1),\dots,\phi(e_m).$ A finitely generated convex cone is polyhedral (the "Farkas-Minkowski-Weyl theorem", see for example Schrijver's "Theory of Linear and Integer Porgramming") and therefore closed. The distance between a point $[u]$ and the closed set $\phi(A)$ disjoint from $[u]$ is positive, which is what we needed to prove.

Comment: Thank you! I hoped for a more elemtary way, which does not need the "Farkas-Minkowski-Weyl Theorem"...

Comment: For an online proof of Weil’s theorem, see, for instance, Theorem 1.8 from *”[Polyhedral Geometry and Linear Optimization. Summer Semester 2010](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~paffenholz/daten/preprints/ln.pdf)”* by Andreas Paffenholz.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to solve this,  but I can help you with one more case. If U is a hyperplane then there is some vector y and constant c such that $U=\{ x: x \cdot y =c \}$. Disjointness implies that $y \geq 0, c<0$. This implies the distance is at least $ - c/ \| y \| $.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I do not see why it should blow up? U could be parallel to one of the faces of A and even if not, I do not see a simple argument.

Comment: @crankk you're absolutely right.  I edited my answer to solve one more special case.

Comment: Assume that $dim(U)<m$ and that $U\cap A=\emptyset$. Does it follow that there is a hyperplane $U'$ with $U\subset U'$ and $U'\cap A = \emptyset$? That would solve the problem...

Comment: I think I am one step away from the solution: Is it true that, given to disjoint convex closed sets $U$ and $V$ there is a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and a non zero $v$ such that either $(x,v)\ge c > (y,v)$ or $(y,v) \ge c >(x,v)$ for all $x\in U$ and $y\in V$?

Comment: @crankk: I don't think that's true for general convex closed sets. E.g. take $U$ to be the closed convex hull of points of the form $(0,y,0)$ and $(1,y,e^y)$ with $y\leq 0,$ and take $V$ to be the closed convex hull of points of the form $(0,y,-e^y)$ and $(1,y,0)$ with $y\leq 0.$ The only separating hyperplane is $z=0,$ which has points from both.

Comment: I see, thank you.